# Remove "nav-tabs" rounded corners (Bootstrap)

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

Don't know how to remove the rounded corner on tabs (class="nab-tabs") in Bootstrap.

Example: http://i.imgur.com/ho7rX.png

Please Help

Thanks

Answer (score 18):

Add this line to the CSS

```
.nav-tabs > li > a {
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
}
```

or in your case:

```
.nab-tabs > li > a {
-webkit-border-radius: 0;
-moz-border-radius: 0;
border-radius: 0;
}
```

**EDIT: 21-03-2018**

there is another way in BS4.0 add ***rounded-0*** the official [bootstrap override](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/utilities/borders/#border-radius), [here is the working example](https://codepen.io/igcorreia/pen/pLPbmE):

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-8 ml-auto mr-auto my-5 ">
      <ul class="nav nav-tabs ">
        <li class="nav-item ">
          <a class="nav-link active rounded-0" href="#">Active</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link rounded-0" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link rounded-0" href="#">Link</a>
        </li>
        <li class="nav-item">
          <a class="nav-link rounded-0 disabled" href="#">Disabled</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: the difference: '.nav-tabs' to '.nab-tabs'. I love programmers and their interpretation

Comment: I had to use border-radius: 0 !important;

Comment: Plus one for the chuckle this brought me

Answer (score 3):

For Bootstrap 4 you can use `.nav-tabs-nostyle`. For example:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-fixed-top navbar-light bg-faded">
  <div class="nav navbar-nav nav-tabs-nostyle">
    <a href="#one" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab">One</a>
    <a href="#two" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Two</a>
    <a href="#three" class="nav-item nav-link" data-toggle="tab">Three</a>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 2):

Go through the CSS file looking for any .nav-tabs entries and look for:

```
-webkit-border-radius
 -moz-border-radius
      border-radius
```

Set them all to 0.

EDIT:

You could also replace with a themed version such as this "flat", "metro" style version:

http://bootswatch.com/cosmo/#buttons